# How to send space as space and not %20 in Alamofire multipart data upload?

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipartform-data, multipart

I am using Alamofire to send a multipart upload for a image file . This is the code I am using to add the parameters . The problem is , it sends space as %20 (A k as A%20K) . I want to send it as it is (A K). This is the code for adding params

```
URLEncoding.default.queryParameters(params).forEach { (key, value) in
if let data = value.data(using: .utf8) {
multipart.append(data, withName: key)
print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as Any)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're using `URLEncoding` to query the parameters and those will always be *URL encoded* as you might expect.

Try removing percentage encoding from the string before converting it to data like

```
if let data = value.removingPercentEncoding?.data(using: .utf8) {
   // do your stuff here
}
```

Assuming your `params` object is an array of `[String: String]` values, you could simply do the following

```
params.forEach { (key, value) in
   if let data = value.data(using: .utf8) {
      multipart.append(data, withName: key)
      print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to append parameters to a multipart data without using url encoding?